# Sharepoint Calendar View Filter - Show items in current year

Tags: filter, calendar, calculated-column-formula

I have events on my calendar that have Start Time dates in 2016, 2017, and 2018. I have a calculated formula on my Calendar list named **Year Calculated Event - Current**.

The formula is

```
=YEAR([Start Time])-YEAR(NOW())
```

I can view the column in Shaded Style. That column displays show "**-1**" for 2016, "**0**" for 2017, or "**1**" for 2018.

The problem I am having is when I try to set up a view filter, the list is blank.

**Filter**

> Show the items when column Year Calculated Event - Current is equal to 0